# Spring login returns to error after successful login at server side

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring

I am hosting my html pages at one server (wamp) and the login authentication and other APIs at another server (jetty). When I call the below code to login to the server it always goes to error even though it successfully authenticated at jetty server.

The same API is giving me a success with RestClient.

I inspected after adding a custom filter in Jetty server and I could see that the response code is 200OK.

```
function login() {
$.ajax({
    url : "http://localhost:8080/testapp/j_spring_security_check",
    type : "POST",
    data : 'j_username=' + $('#userName').val() + '&j_password='
            + $('#loginPassword').val(),
    success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        closeLoginModal();
        alert("Login success");
    },
    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Login failed");
    }
});
```

}

Any Help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the response which you are expecting and what you are actually getting now.

Comment: Also try to debug the JS code in your browser JS console.

Comment: I am getting 404v :( . I am expecting 200

Comment: It means the AJAX code is not even able to hit the server.!!!

Comment: But I debugged the server code. I am getting the control in server and its even authenticated. I am totally confused

Comment: And the same URL copy pasted is working with Rest Client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a filter in my login provider server web.xml and changed the header to accept request from all origin and it worked. I am not sure if this is the right way. But now login is success

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do authentication at one server and the rest of the work on a different server, you have a rather complex triangle setup.

The authentication server will check the authenticity of the user, start a session and issue a cookie. However, the session and the cookie is only valid on the authentication server. You can't use it on the primary server with the HTML pages and the primary server probably doesn't know about the valid session either. That's probably the point where you're stuck.

There are several pieces missing and there's probably more than one way to solve it. The setup I've used in the past is:

- After the authentication on the authentication server, the user is redirected to the primary server to a special URL that includes a ticket number associated with the user's session.
- The primary server then uses a secure connection to connect to the authentication server and verify that the ticket number is valid and to query additional user information.
- If that succeed, it will start a session and issue a separate cookie valid on the primary server.

These actions close the triangle. And they require that the primary server trusts the authentication server.

Implementing it with Ajax adds some additional challenges.

Comment: But still the ajax request should not fail rt ? I am not sure why the ajax request is failing.

Comment: No I solved the problem of authentication. Now I am into this problem. All the subsequent request creates a new session even though I am passing the jSessionID ? Do I need to do something here